# Snyk CLI for docker scan azure pipeline

Tags: azure, security, azure-devops, snyk, devsecops

I need to run snyk scan for Azure container and set it to fail only when there are new vulnerabilities found as compared to previous image.

I did follow the snyk-delta document to configure task in azure but the tasks are getting failed.

Suggestions are to use snyk cli to scan in the azure pipeline.

Not sure how to configure it.

We want to add snyk-delta scan in out pipeline, add CLI script without using Snyk extension.

Any suggestion to do this.

Comment: Have you checked the following steps?

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use a few template that are shared here
https://github.com/snyk-labs/snyk-cicd-integration-examples

You can also send suggestions by sending a Pull Request there.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, we can use the snyk Security task to scan azure pipeline.

https://docs.snyk.io/integrations/ci-cd-integrations/azure-pipelines-integration/add-the-snyk-security-task-to-your-pipelines

And snyk cli, you can try: https://docs.snyk.io/more-info/getting-started/snyk-integrations/docker/scanning-with-the-docker-cli